# new to windows azure powershell and can not connect to my azure app

Tags: powershell, azure

I am getting given error when I use powershell commandlets to connect azure app -

Get-HostedService : Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority ‘management.core.windows.net’.

here is the links I follow -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271300

http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience there could be two problems:

1. The certificate you are using is not able to create a secure SSL tunnel between your computer and Windows Azure Management Portal and you get error
2. I have seen OS specific problems related to SSPI and SCHANEL in which the SSL tunnel could not be created.

I also think the first links you have has old info and does not help in most cases. Lets try to solve problem first which is very easy. I am writing below understanding you have Powershell Cmdlets installed in your machine:

- First download the publishconfig file from your Windows Azure portal as decribed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/05/10/downloading-windows-azure-publish-settings-subscription-configuration-file.aspx).
- Now open your Windows Powershell for Windows Azure CmdLets (In Admin Mode)

After that enter these Powershell Commands directly:

```
PS > Import-Subscription <include your _filename_.publishsettings here>
PS > Select-Subscription <Enter The _name_of_your_subscription which will be listed after you run above command (Note - **SubscriptionName** is needed here>
PS > Get-HostedService <This should list all of services in your subscription>
```

Now you can manage the subscription from Powershell Cmdlets.

If you still have problems please let me know and I will provide info on 2).

Comment: yes working this way. Why not the commandlet documentation say to use publishsettings. I was spending my time to create the certificate and using when publishsettings work without problem.

Comment: Running PS in Admin Mode was the kicker for me.  Otherwise the private key wasn't being read in the certificate store and the SSL tunnel would error like this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please file a bug for this here: http://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools

The error message back from PowerShell should be friendlier in this case.

Also, you can now use Add-AzureAccount to obtain credentials rather than having to download and import a publishsettings file